# Restrict Administrators from changing system time - Windows XP machines (no domain)

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, scripting

I need to write a script that will remove all users under    `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > User Rights Assignment > Change the system time`    from the local group policy (gpedit.msc) on all Windows XP machines.  These machines are not on the domain.  I DO have a way to distribute and run the script automatically.  Can someone point me in the right direction for creating a script like this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, ignoring the fact that an administrator can just change it back.. ;)

The [secedit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786439(WS.10).aspx) tool should provide the functionality you need.  Use `/areas SECURITYPOLICY`.

Comment: I know they can change it back, but they don't know how.  I realize it's not the best idea to give users admin rights.  Without going into detail, it's necessary in this instance.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that administrators can change it back.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but may be useful. You also can try to do it using utility from [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) *ntrights.exe*.

**Example script (tested on Windows XP Professional SP3)**:

```
@echo off

echo Start process %date% %time% >> %~dp0%~n0.log

cd /d "c:\work"

rem Revokes "Change system time" right from Administrators
ntrights.exe -r SeSystemtimePrivilege -u "Administrators" >> %~dp0%~n0.log
rem Revokes "Change system time" right from Power users
ntrights.exe -r SeSystemtimePrivilege -u "Power Users" >> %~dp0%~n0.log
rem Revokes "Change system time" right from user2
ntrights.exe -r SeSystemtimePrivilege -u "user2" >> %~dp0%~n0.log
rem Grant "Change system time" right to user1
ntrights.exe +r SeSystemtimePrivilege -u "user1" >> %~dp0%~n0.log

echo End process %date% %time% >> %~dp0%~n0.log

rem Reboot if you need
shutdown /r /t 10
```